# Libcurl C++ Ldap Request

Tags: c++, ldap, libcurl

i am new to cUrl.
What i need todo is a curl request to an ldap server.

So far the request works fine over the command line: 
**$curl ldap://XXXXXXXXX:389/DC=XXXXXXXXX,DC=DE?mail?sub?(sAMAccountName=XXXXXXXXX) --user s_ad_XXXXXXXXX:Password**

After trying to get this done in my C++ CMake Project. I issued this error Code from
libcurl: 
 **libcurl: (39) LDAP local: ldap_search_ext Bad search filter**

My code as snippet:

```
std::string readBuffer;
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
        CURLcode res;
        char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ldap://XXXXXXXXX:389/DC=XXXXXXXXX,DC=DE?mail?sub?(sAMAccountName=XXXXXXXXX) --user s_ad_XXXXXXXXX:Password");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
        errbuf[0] = 0;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);        // this line prints into console, what curl is trying to do
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1L);   // closes the connection, if not here the connection can be used more than once

        // curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        std::cout << res << std::endl;

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            size_t len = strlen(errbuf);
            fprintf(stderr, "\nlibcurl: (%d) ", res);
            if (len)
                fprintf(stderr, "%s%s", errbuf,
                    ((errbuf[len - 1] != '\n') ? "\n" : ""));
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
}
```

My Output:

```
Test curl library
*   Trying XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
* LDAP local: ldap://XXXXXXXXX:389/DC=XXXXXXXXX,DC=DE?mail?sub?(sAMAccountName=XXXXXXXXX) --user s_ad_XXXXXXXXX:Password
* LDAP local: ldap_search_ext Bad search filter
* Closing connection 0
39


libcurl: (39) LDAP local: ldap_search_ext Bad search filter
```

I appricate every help! **Thank you** for taking the time reading this.

Comment: Use --libcurl command line option to get C code performing the same what the curl command does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just bung everything into the `CURLOPT_OPT_URL` field. The `--user` bit should be separated into a [separate parameter](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERPWD.html):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ldap://XXXXXXXXX:389/DC=XXXXXXXXX,DC=DE?mail?sub?(sAMAccountName=XXXXXXXXX)");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "s_ad_XXXXXXXXX:Password");
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, your Solution was right.

Comment: @Elleshar If this answer has helped you, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Doing so may also help anyone else trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Thanks, Done.